# Weird behavior of Copyq top panel icon?

Tags: indicator, clipboard-manager

I use `copyq` as my clipboard manager and it works fine, but whenever I try to cleaned my system using `BleachBit`(as normal user) top bar icon changes like below image and most of time when i click that copyq icon it open briefly and then close.

[image]

I tried using different themes /icon themes and also i removed copyq and re installed it. No any luck,

What is this problem and how do i solve this? Thanks.

```
Ubuntu 14.04
CopyQ Clipboard Manager v2.2.0 (hluk@email.cz)
Built with: Qt 4.8.6, LibQxt 0.7.0
```

Comment: Any idea ??? please

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested this. Cleaning "System/Temporary Files" with BleachBit removed following files:

```
Delete 4,1kB /tmp/sni-qt_copyq_7487-uq6jv3/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/copyq_7487_3b113d95128bb105a6dd1b89f6652e0a.png
Delete 4,1kB /tmp/sni-qt_copyq_7487-uq6jv3/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/copyq_7487_3b113d95128bb105a6dd1b89f6652e0a.png
Delete 4,1kB /tmp/sni-qt_copyq_7487-uq6jv3/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/copyq_7487_3b113d95128bb105a6dd1b89f6652e0a.png
Delete 4,1kB /tmp/sni-qt_copyq_7487-uq6jv3/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/copyq_7487_3b113d95128bb105a6dd1b89f6652e0a.png
Delete 0 /tmp/unity_support_test.1

Disk space recovered: 16,4kB
Files deleted: 5
```

So it seems that [Ubuntu wrapper library](https://launchpad.net/sni-qt) for displaying [QSystemTrayIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html) stores icon image file in temporary directory. Oddly the library will just use invalid icon if the image is removed.

After CopyQ is restarted icon is back in place.

Removing temporary files randomly is not a good practice. Yes, there could be some stale files, but it may also contain some important data or backups. CopyQ uses temporary files when you edit items in an external editor.

Comment: k. then, i don't have any choices. thanks for the tip and your time.